# How to see the installed version of Apache Mesos?

Tags: command-line-interface, mesos

How does one determine the installed version of Apache Mesos?

`mesos help` on the cli doesn't say...

```
mesos help
Usage: mesos <command> [OPTIONS]

Available commands:
    help
    log
    execute
    ps
    resolve
    cat
    local
    init-wrapper
    tail
    scp
    stop-cluster.sh
    start-masters.sh
    stop-slaves.sh
    slave
    start-cluster.sh
    stop-masters.sh
    daemon.sh
    master
    start-slaves.sh
```

And no man.

```
man mesos
No manual entry for mesos
```

Comment: `sudo yum list installed | grep mesos` did it but. I'm holding out for a better answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the web ui for any Mesos master and see the version number in the top left corner (at least for any fairly recent Mesos, ~0.18+).

You can check the logs for a master or slave, which will always start with the lines "Build: [date] by [user]" and "Version: [version]".

You can also run `mesos-master --version` or `mesos-slave --version`.